# LDAP/ Active Directory Login page

Tags: php, ldap

Background

I am try to create a login page using PHP that connects to users in Active Directory using LDAP.

So far I have been using the LDAP [Test Server](https://www.forumsys.com/2022/05/10/online-ldap-test-server/) and I was able to successfully bind using the Username and Password provided on the website.

However, when I tried binding with the Group using the OU (ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com) the bind was unsuccessfully.

```
 <?php

$ldapuser = "uid=".trim($_POST["username"]).",ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com";
    $ldappass = trim($_POST["password"]);

    $ldapserver = "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389";

    //options are require, never, allow
    //require is most secure, the others could allow for man in the middle attacks
    putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=allow');


    // connect to ldap server
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapserver) or die ("Couldn't connect");

    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = false;
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass);



    //Display success or failure
    if ($ldapbind) {

        if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo "You are not logged in!";
        } else{

            echo "You are logged in!";
        } 

        
    } ?>
```

Here is the error message that was received:

[PHP Stack error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tYvf.png)

Error:
Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in E:\wamp64\www\login-ad\ldap.php on line 23

ldap_bind( $ldap = class LDAP\Connection { }, $dn = 'uid=newton,ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com', $password = 'password' )

Comment: For the username, can you try just `scientists\\newton`? If that doesn't work, maybe try the single slash, I can't remember if that needs to be escaped here or not.

Comment: Thanks for responding @ChrisHaas, However, I still received the same error when I entered the username as "scientists\\newton". I also received this error ("ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid DN syntax") when the username is added with a single stroke "scientists\newton".